# iPhone + stringWithUTF8String + memory leaks

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks

I am using following code in my application to read the string value from database:

```
objPlayer.playerName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
```

When I run the Instruments to find memory leaks it gives me NSCFString leaks at above line.

What should I do, please help me.

Regards.

Comment: How is playerName property defined in your class?

Comment: Vladimir,
NSString *playerName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *playerName;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the property `playerName`, it automatically retains the `NSString` (even though its constructor autoreleases it). So you'll have to release it again at some point (preferably in the `dealloc` method).

When you assign a value to a property declared with the retain flag, as in `@property(retain)`, then whenever you assign a value to that property it does three things: releases the old value, assigns the variable to the new value, and retains the new value. Thus the string you're creating through `stringWithUtf8String:` has a retain count of 1 after that line is executed.

You'll have to release this string at some point, or you'll get a leak. Since it's a property, however, it shouldn't be released before the object that contains it is, so you should put that release statement in your `dealloc` method.

If none of this really makes sense, take a look at the memory management guide Alex linked to.

Comment: Ian, I am not getting what you are saying, can you explain in some detail, please

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSString *_playerName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
objPlayer.playerName = _playerName;
```

Or:

```
NSString *_playerName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)];
objPlayer.playerName = _playerName;
[_playerName release];
```

Please take a moment to read through Apple's [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html), which explains this subject.

Comment: Maybe you can report where Leaks is saying the leak occurs when using the aforementioned code. That might narrow down the problem somewhat.

Comment: Also, `sqlite3_column_text()` returns `const unsigned char *`, and `-initWithUTF8String:` takes a `const char *` according to http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBFGHEH , so there should be no need to cast.

Comment: Finally, are you running on the Simulator or on the device, or both? Sometimes the Simulator will report a memory leak that will not occur on the device, and vice versa. That would be useful information, as well.

Comment: Basically, the more information you can add to your question, the easier it would be for people to help you.